# Multiple dynamics insert

Tags: php, insert

I have the form below with them I can add more rows to insert more values in the mysql table.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>    
    <form action="process" class="register" method="POST">

            <p> 
                <input type="button" value="Add Passenger" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
                <input type="button" value="Remove Passenger" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  /> 
            </p>
           <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <p>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_NAME[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="BX_age">Age</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class="small"  name="BX_age[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="BX_gender">Gender</label>
                        <select id="BX_gender" name="BX_gender[]" required="required">
                            <option>....</option>
                            <option>Male</option>
                            <option>Female</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="BX_birth">Berth Pre</label>
                        <select id="BX_birth" name="BX_birth[]" required="required">
                            <option>....</option>
                            <option>Window</option>
                            <option>No Choice</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                        </p>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="clear"></div>

        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm &raquo;" />

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Now, I want pass the variable (for example: `BX_NAME[]`) with two different values to **insert.php** page:

1. If I have two rows in the form, How to create the insert?
2. How to build a php script to crate dynamics insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it, you want to inset your rows in database with one query. If no tell me to delete this answer.
You'll get each variable in PHP side with it's index. for example:

```
chk[0], BX_Name[0], ..., chk[1], BX_Name[1], ...
```

here you must manage them and generate your query.

```
$insert = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['chk']); $i++)
{
    $chk = isset($_POST['chk'][$i]) ? $_POST['chk'][$i] : '';
    $BX_Name = isset($_POST['BX_Name'][$i]) ? $_POST['BX_Name'][$i] : '';
    // instead of '' you must put default value which your db expect
    ...
    $insert[] = "({$chk}, {$BX_Name}, ...)";
}
$values = implode(', ', $insert);
$query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_test` (`chk`, `bx_name`, ...) VALUES $values";
//execute it
```